# Resize Powershell screen buffer upon window resize

Tags: windows, powershell, window

When I switch Powershell between windowed, maximized, and half-screened (e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>) I'm still limited by the "internal" dimensions specified in the console properties (under layout), and all it accomplishes is showing/hiding scrollbars.

Is there a way to somehow get it to rejigger the buffer size automatically? Bonus points if it can gracefully handle being in Vim or SSH, but I won't get my hopes up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this saving it as Console-sizing.ps1 (I use it in original powershell console, don't know in VIM or SSH or other console if it works!)

```
function Size($w, $h)
{
    New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size($w, $h)
}

Write-Host '[Arrows] resize  [Esc] exit ...'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
for($ui = $Host.UI.RawUI;;) {
    $b = $ui.BufferSize
    $w = $ui.WindowSize
    switch($ui.ReadKey(6).VirtualKeyCode) {
        37 {
            $w = Size ($w.width - 1) $w.height
            $ui.WindowSize = $w
            $ui.BufferSize = Size $w.width $b.height
            break
        }
        39 {
            $w = Size ($w.width + 1) $w.height
            $ui.BufferSize = Size $w.width $b.height
            $ui.WindowSize = $w
            break
        }
        38 {
            $ui.WindowSize = Size $w.width ($w.height - 1)
            break
        }
        40 {
            $w = Size $w.width ($w.height + 1)
            if ($w.height -gt $b.height) {
                $ui.BufferSize = Size $b.width $w.height
            }
            $ui.WindowSize = $w
            break
        }
        27 {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:
Please read comment to know the [original function coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323582/roman-kuzmin)**

Comment: It looks like taken from [here](http://nightroman.wordpress.com/2006/11/17/resize-console-ps1-resize-console-windowbuffer-using-arrow-keys/)

Comment: @RomanKuzmin - It 's so! Do not remember where I got it! Thank you Roman!! If it needed I can delete my answer and you can answer  it with the link to you blog..

Comment: Please, keep the answer, I like it :)

Comment: This is pretty good, but it is manual using the arrow keys, not automatic, so I'm leaving the question open...

Comment: @RomanKuzmin Okay, I feel dumb.  I saved it then dot-sourced it, but nothing happened.  If I open & run the script within the ISE, I get "[Arrows] resize [Esc] exit, but nothing happens when I use the arrow keys, do Win+Arrow keys, or hit Esc.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mbourgon, this script is designed for console windows, not ISE.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a system audit app using PowerShell, so I can easily dump to a non XML based html file, preformatted for reporting.

Part of it is using a tool set I have compiled, and part of THAT uses a custom menu (PS) that I am creating, to make it look nice and professional, I use a batch file to run the powershell and bypass the UAC and settings for running restricted ps1 files.  But to make it look really pretty, I set the width, height and it's position, as well as the buffer size, and set all the menus to have it all fit perfectly in the window...

Below is the code I use for the settings of the window.

Hope it helps.

```
# Use as short code for everything else.
$uisettings = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI

# Set the title of the window itself.
$uisettings.WindowTitle = "Something you want it to say."

# Sets the style of the cursor, 100 = full block (easier to see).
$uisettings.CursorSize = "100"

# Set the window size for the screen.  
$b = $uisettings.WindowSize
$b.Width = 80
$b.Height = 60
$uisettings.WindowSize = $b

# Set the position on the screen for the window. 
$x = $uisettings.WindowPosition
$x.x = 0
$x.y = 0
$uisettings.WindowPosition = $x

# Set the buffer size;
# use the below code to set the buffer to OTHER than the WindowSize above.
# OR, if you want to ensure it fits just right, remove lines 1, 2 and 3 below,
# and set $uisettings.BufferSize to $b instead.
$s = $uisettings.BufferSize
$s.Width = 80
$s.Height = 60
$uisettings.BufferSize = $s
```

Answer (score 0):

The following powershell function mimics the cmd
mode 120 40

```
 function mode ($1,$2){
 $s = (get-host).ui.rawui
 $b = $s.buffersize
 $b.height = $2
 $b.width = $1
 $s.buffersize = $b
 $w = $s.windowsize
 $w.height = $2
 $w.width = $1
 $s.windowsize = $w
 }
```